# How i can put a music in setAudioSource() method in android?

Tags: android, audio, put

I'm a android programmer . I want to record music sound or put a music in setAudioSource() method of MediaRecorder class . but i can't do this . can you help me ?

```
private void startRecord() throws IllegalStateException, IOException { // 
recorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
//ok so I say audio source is the microphone
//is it windows/linux microphone on the emulator?
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GP‌​P); 
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/Music/"+System.currentTimeMi‌​llis()+".amr"); 
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start(); }
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't do this? Is there an error or something?

Comment: This method want music source (int) . i don't know how  find my music source id .

Comment: Please include the source code in your question. It's hard for us to guide you without enough information. If possible include some pictures too

Comment: Please put it inside the question, not in the comment. It is hard for us to read the code.